# 0 supported devices in google play store

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-console

I uploaded the apk on the play store and it says 0 devices are supported, I changed targeted sdk also, as it was suggested in another answer but it did not work.

manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.eadevelopers.tatto">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <permission android:name="com.eadevelopers.tatto.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" android:required="true"/>


    <application
        android:name="com.eadevelopers.tatto.Global"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_80"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true">


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.eadevelopers.tatto"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            minifyEnabled false




        }

        debug {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            minifyEnabled false

        }

    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/mint-5.1.0.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'

}
```

These are my manifest and gradle files. I have changed target sdk version but that did not work I think the problem is somewhere in permissions but I don't  know where. I already uploaded 3 apks with changes but the supported devices are still 0.

Comment: Most likely conflicting requirements. I'm guessing no device has ALL `<uses-feature` you listed.

Comment: `android:required="false"`

Comment: Remove  <permission android:name="com.eadevelopers.tatto.CAMERA" /> and add 'android:required="false"' to all uses-feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I got the fixed. comment by Jay.

```
Remove <permission android:name="com.eadevelopers.tatto.CAMERA" /> and add 'android:required="false"' to all uses-feature. – Jay Jun 28 at 8:08
```